# Combining all combinations of two lists into a dict of special form

Tags: python, list, dictionary, combinations

I have two lists:

```
var_a = [1,2,3,4]

var_b = [6,7]
```

I want to have a list of dicts as follows:

```
result = [{'a':1,'b':6},{'a':1,'b':7},{'a':2,'b':6},{'a':2,'b':7},....]
```

I think the result should be clear.

Comment: Is the name of variables available to you in a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [6,7]
[dict(zip(('a','b'), (i,j))) for i,j in product(a,b)]
```

yields

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 6},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 7},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 6},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 7},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 6},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 7},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 6},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 7}]
```

Comment: Why the tuple unpacking and repacking?

Comment: Figured it was instructive for OP to see what is returned from `product`. Was the same reason that I zipped `('a', 'b')` and not `'ab'`.

Comment: This seems to be just a bit more intuitive than what @inspectorG4dget answered (although he got more votes, for some reason). Thx.

Answer (score 5):

```
[{k:v for k,v in itertools.izip('ab', comb)} for comb in itertools.product([1,2,3,4], [6,7])]

>>> import itertools
>>> [{k:v for k,v in itertools.izip('ab', comb)} for comb in itertools.product([
1,2,3,4], [6,7])]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 7}, {'a': 2, 'b': 6}, {'a': 2, 'b': 7}, {'a': 3
, 'b': 6}, {'a': 3, 'b': 7}, {'a': 4, 'b': 6}, {'a': 4, 'b': 7}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the name of variables is given to you, you could use.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [6,7]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> nameTup = ('a', 'b')
>>> [dict(zip(nameTup, elem)) for elem in product(a, b)]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 7}, {'a': 2, 'b': 6}, {'a': 2, 'b': 7}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6}, {'a': 3, 'b': 7}, {'a': 4, 'b': 6}, {'a': 4, 'b': 7}]
```